# Calculate average fidelity of QobjEvo

Tags: qutip, gate-fidelity

I am using QuTip to simulate a quantum gate, and I want to calculate the average fidelity of the gate.
I have the Hamiltonian, the interaction time, and Liouvillian modeling the decoherence.
Is there any easy way that I can get average fidelity from above objects?
If there is not, then how to do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you know which quantum gate you want to implement, you can use the following function:  `average_gate_fidelity` [average_gate_fidelity](https://qutip.org/docs/4.0.2/modules/qutip/metrics.html). You need to provide your target unitary (i.e., the gate you want to implement) and your superoperator. Alternatively, you can use the Qiskit version of the function, which accepts the unitary you have implemented and your target unitary [qiskit version](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.19/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.average_gate_fidelity.html). Since you can easily convert one matrix type to the other, it doesn't really matter which library you are using, as long as you specify the matrix types carefully (e.g., Qobj or Superoperator, etc.).

Comment: Thank you. However, the function average_gate_fidelity in QuTip accepts an operator and a target unitary, instead of Hamiltonian and interaction time. Or I have missed something?

Comment: you wrote you have Liouvillian modeling and this already represents a superoperator. I do not know your code so it is hard to tell something more but I am sure you can give Liouvillian operator: Superoperators and Liouvillians (https://qutip.org/docs/latest/apidoc/functions.html)